# Output Django Charfield as a responsive Bootstrap textarea

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

If I have a form containing a `CharField` and select the Textarea-widget, then I can specify the number of rows and columns for the textarea, but this output will not be responsive.

In short: How can I output my form field using Bootstrap's Textarea-widget or make the default one responsive.

Comment: Have you already tried applying the various [control classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

what about setting `max-width: 100%;` on the textarea ?

**EDIT** after comments:

I still think the above method could be a simple and direct solution for your case, because it's easy to put that in the css and render all the forms responsive without overriding your field widget or the template for that field.

Otherwise you could consider using [django-crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) , and do something like:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
...
{{ form|crispy }}
```

or using the tag only on the desired field: `{{ form.textfield|crispy }}`

it will render your form with the bootstrap template if you set in your config `CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Mark actually it renders the textarea responsive, without overriding the form template or form widgets.

Comment: Don't you mean plain `width`? `max-width` definitely won't scale things up.

Comment: So I didn't get it to work by setting `max-width: 100%;` (didn't see any effect). However, if I added `class="form-control"` to the textarea it became responsive (after going through the form controls as suggested by Burhan). Maybe this was a typical noob mistake? Guess, I don't really understand what the form-control class does.

Comment: @Jimbo84 differently form-control sets width: 100%, and so it "ignores" your cols settings, look at this really simple example http://jsfiddle.net/ndhkjj02/ for the first method.

Comment: @DRC yeah, I can see that from your example - good to know. But I'm curious to why I didn't see any effect when just applying the CSS.

Comment: @Jimbo84 sorry but I'm not really sure without viewing your code or a working example somewhere.

Comment: @DRC removed my old CSS file and then it worked, I had probably added something that messed it up.